# How to transpose a jagged 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm trying to transpose a jagged 2D array called "seats."

```
seats = np.array([
                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                  [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                  [1, 2, 3], 
                  [1, 2, 3, 4,],
                  [1, 2],
                  [1, 2]
                 ], dtype = object)
```

I want to turn "seats" into an array looking like this:

```
transposed_seats = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5]
```

)

**Is this possible?**

I've tried the transpose function of numpy and zip, but none of that seems to work.

Comment: No, it's not possible with numpy. You have a list of lists at best - do not use numpy for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Transpose List of Lists of various lengths - 3.3 easiest method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529447/python-transpose-list-of-lists-of-various-lengths-3-3-easiest-method)

Comment: This array is not 2d.  Check its shape.  That array is more like list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use itertools zip_longest.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest

seats = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2]
], dtype=object)
```

directly, use zip_longest

```
list(zip_longest(*seats))
#[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3, None, None), (4, 4, None, 4, None, None), (5, None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Now, if you **do not** want `None` in your output then:

```
list([x for x in y if x is not None] for y in zip_longest(*seats))

#output
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: Note that you should explicitly discard None by checking `x is None`,  otherwise you would also discard zeros in more general situations.

Comment: Thanks Goku. The list comprehension with None check is perfect.

Comment: What if I want to discard trailing Nones, but I don't want to discard inner Nones? Ie in the example above I'd want `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, None, 4], [5]]`

Comment: Thats a good question @Stef. Do you have anything in mind ?